# How to cbind data.frames with differing lengths without knowing the lengths of the data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe, cbind

I am hoping to find a way to cbind data.frames with differing lengths, but I want to cbind the data.frames without having to specify the lengths. As the lengths of the data.frames I will be working with will vary I do not want to find the lengths before I use a cbind.

Current Error I am receiving

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 8, 10
```

Desired Output with blank

```
         A B
rwone    1 2
rwtwo    2 2
rwthree    3
```

Desired Output with NA

```
         A  B
rwone    1  2
rwtwo    2  2
rwthree  NA 3
```

I have tried.

```
length(A) = length(B)

cbind(A,B)
```

I have also tried.

```
if(length(A)<length(B)) {
     if(first==1) A = c(rep(NA, length(B)-length(A)),A);B=B
     if(first==0) A = c(A,rep(NA, length(B)-length(A)));B=B
} 

if(length(B)<length(A)) {
     if(first==1) B = c(rep(NA, length(A)-length(B)),B);A=A
     if(first==0) B = c(y,rep(NA, length(A)-length(B)));A=A
} 

cbind(A,B)
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Dre

Comment: You probably want a `merge`

Comment: When I used a `merge` the second data.frame was added to the bottom of the first data.frame like a `rbind`. I would like the two data.frames to be side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge is most straightforward when you're merging on a column of a dataframe as opposed to the rownames. If you assign a column in both dataframes to be the same as the rownames, then merge should work. This worked for me:

```
A = data.frame(A = c(1, 2))
B = data.frame(B = c(2,2,3))
A$key = row.names(A)
B$key = row.names(B)

merge(A, B, all = TRUE)
```

You could also use `join` from the `plyr` library.

```
library(plyr)
join(A, B, by = "key", type = "full")
```

Answer (score 0):

small modification to Nancy's answer using merge based on [this post](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-merge-data-frames-in-R-without-a-common-key)

```
A = data.frame(A = c(1, 2))
B = data.frame(B = c(2,2,3))
A$key = 1:nrow(A)
B$key = 1:nrow(B)

merge(A, B, all = TRUE)
```